# Отправка БД запроса для проверки актуальности данных

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Имеется сервер на **Flask** с библиотекой **SQLAlchemy**. В коде есть функция, допустим, `my_method`, которая отправляет запрос в БД **PostgreSQL** для сравнения дат с текущим днём:

```
    competition.end_date < datetime.date(datetime.today())
```

Мне нужно, чтобы эта проверка выполнялась каждые, к примеру, 30 минут.
Я нашел следующий код:

```
    import time, traceback

    def every(delay, task):
    next_time = time.time() + delay
    while True:
       time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
       try:
           task()
       except Exception:
           traceback.print_exc()      
       next_time += (time.time() - next_time) // delay * delay + delay
```

А потом запускал так:

```
   threading.Thread(target=lambda: every(1800, my_method)).start()
```

Код работает, но мне кажется есть и другой способ это сделать, потому что я, например, не могу после запуска этого файла остановить его при помощи **Ctrl + c**.

Есть какие-то идеи? Буду благодарен за любую помощь:)

PS. Может есть какое-то решение именно с помощью **Flask**?

Comment: может с Библиотекой scheduler что то можно придумать

Comment: Зачем такие трудности? Просто напиши скрипт который это делает а потом при помощи systemd зашедуль его исполнение. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Timers_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)